# Merge Multiple Tabs in Excel Using Fixed Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies in advance as I'm sure this is a simple question, and there's lots of similar answers out there, but I haven't been able to leverage them into a working solution.

My situation is I have an Excel file with 28 tabs.  Each Sheet has data in the exact same format in range A1:N10000. Note though that some of the cells in each tab are blank.  This holds true across every tab.  I would like to have all 28 tabs merged into one new Sheet call Combined.

I have been trying to leverage this Macro:

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Obviously I've encountered problems running this and the resulting data only has a few values pasted instead of the expected ~280,000 rows (28 tabs, 10k rows each).  I suspect one of the reasons is because there are blank cells in the tabs, so this Macro isn't reading the data as I intend it to.  How can I modify it just to copy A1:N10000 in each tab and paste each to the Combined tab?  Also, will I hit issues with trying to populate a sheet with 280,000 rows?

Thank you!
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentRegion` will not copy everything you want if there are blank cells, as you suspected. Also, it's preferable to avoid using `Select` - since you don't really need to select the cells before copying - and `On Error Resume Next` - this doesn't handle errors at all, it ignores them.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Combine()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim combinedWs As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Add combined worksheet and populate headers
    Set combinedWs = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1))
    combinedWs.Name = "Combined"
    Sheets(2).Rows(1).Copy combinedWs.Rows(1)

    ' Loop through rest of Sheets
    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set ws = Sheets(i)
        With ws
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Set copyRng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, "N"))
            copyRng.Copy combinedWs.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you want to copy a specific, hard-coded range, replace the code inside `With ws... End With`.

```
Set copyRng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(10000, 14))
copyRng.Copy combinedWs.Cells(2, 1).Offset((i-2)*copyRng.Rows.Count)
```

A bit of a hack on the last line: for each iteration of `i` you are offsetting by the number of rows in `copyRng`. You start in `combinedWs.Cells(2, 1)`, or  `A2`. On the first iteration, `i - 2` = 0, so there is no offset. On subsequent iterations, you offset 9999, 19998, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this but I'm encountering one issue.  In some of my tabs, row 9,999 will have data populated in every column from A through N, yet row 10,000 will have data populated in only columns E through H.  In these instances I've noticed that the 10,000th row does not copy over to the combined tab.  I suspect this is related to xlUp in the lastRow variable but I've been tweaking it without success.  Any ideas?

Comment: `Set copyRng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(10000,14))`. I'll revise the answer - you also need to modify the copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you!  This might be a nitpicky, but I noticed the combined tab now includes a blank column A.  It's not a big deal since I can just delete it, but just curious which section of the code is causing that to happen.  VBA is beyond me...

Comment: @urdearboy - you shouldn't have deleted your original comment about fixed ranges - you were right lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim cmbSheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim tmpIndex As Double
    Set cmbSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    cmbSheet.Name = "Combined"
    tmpIndex = 0
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Combined" Then
            If tmpIndex = 0 Then
                cmbSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet Name"
                ws.Range("A1:N1").Copy Destination:=cmbSheet.Cells(1, 2)
            End If
            ws.Range("A2:N10000").Copy Destination:=cmbSheet.Cells((tmpIndex * 10000) + 2 - tmpIndex, 2)
            cmbSheet.Cells((tmpIndex * 10000) + 2, 1).Value = ws.Name
            tmpIndex = tmpIndex + 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```